# Error installing Pygame on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, installation, ubuntu-14.04

So I've been following some instructions on how to install Pygame from this link here :http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?showpart=0#section_0.3

The the final three commands are as follows

```
$
# Use mercurial to clone current code
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame

# Build and install
cd pygame
sudo python3 setup.py
$
```

When I run the final command to run the setup file, I get this error after everything before it runs fine.

```
building 'pygame.imageext' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -DENABLE_NEWBUF=1 -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/SDL -I/usr/include/SDL -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/imageext.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/imageext.o
In file included from src/pygame.h:32:0,
                 from src/imageext.c:49:
src/_pygame.h:80:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Any ideas as to how I cann fix this issue and complete my Pygame installation?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the python development package, which includes those header files.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```